# Performance of ternary operator vs if-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-operator

Is there a difference in performance between the if-else statement and the ternary operator in Python?

Comment: Just use whichever you feel makes the code more readable. If you're ever in a hot loop where it really may make a difference, code it both ways and measure the performance in the context of your actual code. There are likely to be other factors that are more important, such as the algorithm you use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I doubt there is a performance difference.  They compile to equivalent sequences of bytecodes:

```
>>> def f():
...   return a if b else c
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (b)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (a)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
        >>    8 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (c)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def g():
...   if b:
...     return a
...   else:
...     return c
...
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (b)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  3           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (a)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>    8 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (c)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

As with most performance questions, the answer is to measure.

Answer (score 0):

From some testing on Python 3.6.1, it seems like the full statement is faster.

My Results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("""3 if True else 8""")
0.012174860001323395
>>> timeit.timeit("""3 if False else 8""")
0.019092951000857283
>>> timeit.timeit("""if True:
...     3
... else:
...     8""")
0.009110345999943092
>>> timeit.timeit("""if False:
...     3
... else:
...     8""")
0.00877297099941643
```

Comment: I think that may have more to do with `timeit` attempting to parse the triple quoted comment. I defined functions to evaluate that condition with an if-else statement and a ternary operator, used `timeit.repeat` for both with 100 repetitions, and got an average (for the default 1,000,000 run-throughs) of 0.81 seconds for the ternary operator, 0.88 seconds for the if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here're my tests in IPython 7.2.0 (which has `%timeit`, a built-in timing method that makes it extremely easy to measure executions. By default it makes 7 runs and 100 million loops each, so the results should usually be valid) used by PyCharm 2018.3.4 Community Edition x64, running CPython 3.7.2 x64. The OS is Window$ 10.0.17134 Enterprise x64:

```py
##The 1st 2 are without quoting the statement to see how it affects the test.
%timeit 3 if True else 8
14.7 ns ± 0.319 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

%timeit 3 if False else 8
18.1 ns ± 0.211 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

##----------------------------------------------------------------------------

%timeit 'if True:\n    3\nelse:\n    8'
8.67 ns ± 0.314 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

%timeit 'if False:\n    3\nelse:\n    8'
8.4 ns ± 0.0598 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

##----------------------------------------------------------------------------

##The last 2 are with quoting the statement.
%timeit '3 if True else 8'
8.73 ns ± 0.256 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)

%timeit '3 if False else 8'
9.37 ns ± 0.215 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

I think the numbers speak for the statements. A shame really, cuz I love the ternary op.

However, the ternary op's still absolutely useful, especially in the cases where covering all the possibilities in function call params would create a massive repeating of code, which I absolutely hate.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on couple of OS and found ternary performed slower than if else condition

```
import timeit

def ternary_even_odd(num):
    return 2 if num % 2 == 0 else 1
def if_else_even_odd(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

# Run benchmark with different input sizes
input_sizes = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
for size in input_sizes:
    num_runs = 10000  # Adjust iterations based on your needs
    ternary_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: [ternary_even_odd(i) for i in range(size)], number=num_runs)
    if_else_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: [if_else_even_odd(i) for i in range(size)], number=num_runs)

    print(f"Input size: {size}, Ternary time: {ternary_time:.6f} seconds, If-else time: {if_else_time:.6f} seconds")
```

This code can be tested to check the performance.

Comment: Which Python version did you use, which result numbers did you find?